# Meaning of 〜の前では in the following sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

A boxer is watching the super featherweight champion fighting and praises his speed:

> あの速さにダメージを与えるため〝芯〟を射抜くのは[８]【フル】ラウンドでも難しい…！！ ベルトをとった あの王者の…　武器【スピード】**の前では**。

Considering the context, I think that in the second sentence he is saying that what allowed the champion to win the belt is his speed. Could 〜の前では have the meaning of "thanks to"? Otherwise, I don't know how to interpret it here. Is it a grammar structure I am unaware of? Has something been omitted? Is the sentence incomplete? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an incomplete sentence. The remaining part is something like:

> ベルトをとったあの王者のスピードの前では勝てない
>
> ベルトをとったあの王者のスピードの前では無力だ

The では here tells you that the omitted phrase is based previous information. That previous part builds up the image of the 王者's impressive strength due to his speed. Therefore, we expect the following phrase to be the logical conclusion, that you cannot win against that strength (given normal circumstances).